# Post processing code after NPM module install

Tags: node.js, npm

Is it possible to run any post processing script after installing NPM module automatically.

I have a case where, I can install some specific NPM modules in my node.js project. After installation of NPM module, I need to update some places in project automatically.

Is it doable?

Answer (score 1):

Yes. Add a `postinstall` script to your `package.json` as described in the [npm documentation](https://npmjs.org/doc/misc/npm-scripts.html)